# Making image-source swap faster

Tags: c#, performance, silverlight

I have 4 image controls and a button, which swaps all those images within those image-controls. But this is going too slow.

The image swap happens after a 1.5s Storyboard animation. So imagine those four-image controls making a move down and then calling this method:

```
 BLOCK4.Source = stack[3];
 BLOCK3.Source = stack[2];
 BLOCK2.Source = stack[1];
 BLOCK1.Source = stack[0];
```

stack is a private `BitmapImage[] stack;` array which contains random images after every animation-call.

Do you see a way to tune this code in order to make the swap seemingly faster?

**This is what happens:** Animation starts -> stops -> I can see old images -> milliseconds pass by -> I can see new images.

Answer (score 0):

Changing image positions instead of changing sources will be more fancy visual effect on users